# Zeroconf / Avahi mDNS resolution on Android

Tags: dns

I'm running CyanogenMod 12.1 Android on a tablet. I'd like to access local servers and services that I have on my LAN which are advertised using Avahi with foo.local style names. When I try this in Chrome or the built-in browser, the DNS lookup fails.

Is there any way to enable this?

```
-Olin
```

Comment: Did you find anything?